# CF Push failed with could not find a version of dotnet-runtime to install

Tags: deployment, azure-pipelines, cloud-foundry

At global.json I'm defining my .NET SDK Version which is 6.0.302. The azure Pipeline restores, builds and publishes with this version the .NET App. TargetFramework in *.csproj is set to net6.0

this is my manifest:

```
---
applications:
  - name: ((app-name))
    buildpacks:
      - https://my.repo.com/dotnet-core_buildpack-cached-cflinuxfs3-v2.4.1.zip
    env:
      ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT: ((env))
      spring__cloud__config__uri: ((config-server-route))
      spring__cloud__config__failFast: true
    routes:
      - route: ((app-route-internal))
    stack: cflinuxfs3
    memory: 128MB
    services:
      - ((database-service-name))
    health-check-type: http
    health-check-http-endpoint: /management/health
```

CF buildpack 2.4.1 (contains .NET Runtime 6.0.9) and my .NET App with the .NET SDK 6.0.302 matches with each other but I'm receiving following error when I try to "cf push" the .NET App and I don't know why??

[Unable to install dotnet-runtime: could not find a version of dotnet-runtime to install. Failed to compile droplet: Failed to run finalize script: exit status 12](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RgJYw.png)

- Unable to install dotnet-runtime: could not find a version of dotnet-runtime to install

  - Failed to compile droplet: Failed to run finalize script: exit status 12

I expected that cf push command runs successfully and deploys my .NET APP.

Edit:
The 6.0.302 with 2.4.1 buildpack is working with the Artifacts of another Pipeline

[image]

-Installing libgdiplus 6.1 is missing somehow

Answer (score 0):

Double-check the [versions included in the v2.4.1 buildpack](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/dotnet-core-buildpack/releases/tag/v2.4.1) - it looks to me like you'll need to either use 6.0.401, or you might be able to just drop the global.json entirely

Comment: Unfortunately 6.0.302 with buildpack 2.4.1 is working with the result of artifacts of another pipeline.